# Como inserir a Connection String em um projeto console no .NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, console

O appsettings.json no .NET CORE 3.1 não existe mais, foi integrado ao .csproj.

Gostaria de saber como configurar minha connection string, o projeto console no .net core 3.1 é criado apenas com Dependencies e Program.cs.

Dentro do .csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

<Project>
```

Comment: De conde você tirou essa informação sobre o appsettings.json no 3.1?

Comment: Veja o tutorial https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Oque achei estranho é que, passei um código do .net framework 4.6.1 para .net core 3.1, mas ao criar o programa console no 3.1 o appsettings.json não vem por default.